# How do I attach this method to a newly appended element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, append, swipe

So this method `$('#swipeMe li').swipeDelete();` works fine when I attach it to an element, but when I append a new list item using

```
$('.submitAsset').click(function(){
    var asset = $('#asset_number').val();
    $('.accounts  #swipeMe').append('<li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">' + asset + '</a></li>');
    $(this).swipeDelete();
    $('#assetForm').slideUp();    
});
```

It doesn't take effect.  How do I attach this plugin correctly so that items added to the list also have the swipe delete?  Thanks.

None of the answers have worked thus far.  I must have explained it incorrectly.  Here is my html:

```
<div class="accounts">
<h2>CC Acounts </h2>
<div id="CreditCards">
        <ul id="swipeMe">
            <li ><a href="#">This works</a></li>
            <li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">This works<</a></li>
            <li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">This works<</a></li>
            <li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">This works<</a></li>
            <li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">This works<</a></li>
            <li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">This works<</a></li>
            <li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">This works<</a></li>                
            <li >This doesn't</li>      
        </ul>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
        $('#swipeMe li').swipeDelete();

    $('#swipeMe li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).trigger('swiperight')
        });
```

Again all the added elements in the html work well, but none of the appended have the swipeDelete functionality.

Here is the whole Plugin:

```
/*
Name: jquery.swipeButton.js
Author: Andy andyMatthews
Website: http://andyMatthews.net
Version: 1.2.1
*/
(function($){

$.fn.swipeDelete = function(o){

    o = $.extend( {}, $.fn.swipeDelete.defaults, o );

    return this.filter('[data-swipeurl]').each(function(i, el){
        var $e = $(el);
        var $parent = $(el).parent('ul');

        $e.on(o.direction, function ( e ) {

            // reference the current item
            var $li = $(this);
            var cnt = $('.ui-btn', $li).length;

            // remove all currently displayed buttons
            $('div.ui-btn, .' + o.btnClass, $parent).animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 200, function(e) {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            // if there's an existing button we simply delete it, then stop
            if (!cnt) {
                // create button
                var $swipeBtn = $('<a>' + o.btnLabel + '</a>').attr({
                                    'data-role': 'button',
                                    'data-mini': true,
                                    'data-inline': 'true',
                                    'class': (o.btnClass === 'aSwipeBtn') ? o.btnClass : o.btnClass + ' aSwipeBtn',
                                    'data-theme': o.btnTheme,
                                    'href': $li.data('swipeurl')
                                })
                                .on('click tap', o.click);

                // slide insert button into list item
                $swipeBtn.prependTo($li).button();
                $li.find('.ui-btn').hide().animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 200);

                // override row click
                $('div a:not(' + o.btnClass + ')', $li).on('click.swipe', function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).off('click.swipe');
                    $li.removeClass('ui-btn-active').find('div.ui-btn').remove();
                });

            }


        });

    });
};

$.fn.swipeDelete.defaults = {
    direction: 'swiperight',
    btnLabel: 'niko',
    btnTheme: 'e',
    btnClass: 'aSwipeBtn',
    click: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('li').slideUp();
    }
};

 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Btw, this selector `'.accounts  #swipeMe'` should be just `'#swipeMe'`

Answer (score 3):

Within your `click()` handler `this` is the clicked item, so `$(this).swipeDelete();` is applying the method to the `.submitAsset` element, not to your newly added li element. To call `.swipeDelete()` for the item you are appending do this:

```
$('.submitAsset').click(function(){
    var asset = $('#asset_number').val();
    $('<li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">' + asset + '</a></li>')
        .appendTo('#swipeMe').swipeDelete();
    $('#assetForm').slideUp();    
});
```

Rather than first select the `#swipeMe` element and use `.append()`, I've changed it around to first create the new li element and then `.appendTo()`, because that way you have a reference to the new element and can call `.swipeDelete()` on it.

Note that you can likely change your `'.accounts  #swipeMe'` selector to just `'#swipeMe'`, because there should be only one element with that id (unless you want the code to have no effect unless that element is within an `.accounts` element).

Comment: Not sure y this isn't working.  It makes perfect sense. I added all the pertinent information.  Thanks a lot for trying.  I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to target the newly created element. You are trying to target `this` which is the element you clciked on that triggers the creation of the new element

Replace:

```
$(this).swipeDelete();
```

WIth

```
$('#swipeMe li').last().swipeDelete();
```